# Can't click on 'Accept' cookies, how to find correct frame?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, click, browser-automation

I am trying to click on 'Alles accepteren' (in english: Accept all) in the cookie pop-up but nothing seems to work. It probably has to do with focusing on the right window. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.hornbach.nl/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='??']")))

cookie = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Alles accepteren']")))
```

Comment: full XPath of that accept button is 
 `/html/body/div[8]//div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button[3]`  Xpath `//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/button[3]`, could you try with this?

Comment: You mean like this?
`driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/button[3]').click()`

Tried that and didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of accepting cookies on that website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://www.hornbach.nl/'

browser.get(url) 
parent_el = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="usercentrics-root"]')))
parent_el_shadow_root = parent_el.shadow_root 
t.sleep(5)
accept_all_button = parent_el_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')
accept_all_button.click()
print('accepted cookies')
```

Bear in mind this way of locating the shadow root only works for Chrome/chromedriver, and you will need other methods if using Firefox or other browser/driver.
Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Yes it works, thankyou so much! Although i don't understand exactly why. Is it because the cookie pop-up window was located in the 'shadow root'?

Comment: You're welcome @Dion That's right, the cookie popup is located in a shadow root element.