# Selenium can't find dynamially loaded input field element even after waiting for that specific element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to access an input field of username (of login page) with Selenium. The page is JavaScript based.
`driver.get()` wait by default to load the complete page. In my case, it is unable to load that.
I can inspect the element on browser (firefox) and I get this.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" name="username">
```

I tried to wait for that specific element with `EC.presence_of_element_located`.

Code trials:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url) 
delay = 10 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

print(driver.page_source)
```

I get `Loading took too much time!`. Even though the element is there as  I can inspect it in the browser. I also tried `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'input')))` but It also can't find the tag.

Update from the comments: url='https://drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login'

Comment: That element is in a #shadow root. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671844/cant-click-on-accept-cookies-how-to-find-correct-frame/73671977#73671977

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558947/python-selenium-alert-like-authentication-pop-up) tell me if that works for you!

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus That's not a _`#shadow root`_ really but _Windows Authentication_.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium you're wrong: https://imgur.com/MlWp2iT.png. That *is* a shadow root element.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus OP isn't pointing to any `<div>` but an `<input>` field. However accessing the mentioned [url](https://drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login) opens the [Windows Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Gh3.png).

Comment: No @undetectedSelenium. Look closely at the following printscreen: https://imgur.com/NtdmDbQ.png. See the input highlighted, see the url. That specific element is within a shadow root.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Possibly the UI renders differently in APAC, UK and US :/

Comment: That might be the case indeed, @undetectedSelenium.

Comment: @everyone, 
Basically, when you open the website with Chrome, you get the login prompt [login prompt](https://i.ibb.co/MZ4zypb/chrome.jpg).
But when you use Firefox, you don't get it and you are directly into the [login form page](https://i.ibb.co/D8yNJT2/firefox.jpg). 

The login prompt is of no use. The login form page is the actual login page. I can click on cancel button on login prompt to proceed further to login form page in chrome.
Also, I can use `username:password@url` to get rid of login prompt in chrome. But, again login page form happens after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interact a ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *NAME*:

  ```
  myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

However on accessing the [website](https://drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login) I find the *username* field implemented through [Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329228/7429447)

[image: inditex]

---

### Solution

Incase of [***Basic Authentication***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371455/7429447) you need to embed the ***username*** and ***password*** within the url as follows:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login")
```

---

### Update

Additionally the ***username*** field is within nested [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python)

[image: username]
To send a character sequence to the ***username*** field you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763793/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("http://username:password@drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login")
  time.sleep(10)
  item = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('glyph-splash.hydrated').shadowRoot.querySelector('glyph-login-form.hydrated').shadowRoot.querySelector('input[name="username"]')''')
  item.send_keys("ShaidaMuhammad")
  ```

Comment: Basically, the `driver.get("http://username:password@drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login")` will only remove the login prompt, but after that, the actual login page happens. Even if you just click on `cancel` on the login prompt, you will get the actual login page form where the `username` and `password` fields are happened. Now the problem start from their. I can't access those field even I used `EC.presence_of_element_located`. I can inspect the element in the browser but can't access it in the code as the field is not accessable somehow.

Comment: Also, I tried this method. I used `driver.get("http://username:password@drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login")` to get rid of that prompt but then I ended up on the same login form and same problem happened as I explain in the question. Also, I used `EC.element_to_be_clickable` i.e. copy pasted your code.

Comment: It didn't work in first place i.e. I pasted the code above the code I wrote in the question. Then, I posted below the code. Interestingly, the code worked then. Even though I got the same error again `Loading took too much time!`. but the keys were successfully sent. Now the problem is after clicking login, it stuck on authentication. Is there any problem in sending keys to the fields. Or the website has some blocking mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558947/python-selenium-alert-like-authentication-pop-up), so your code would looks like

```
url='https://user:password@drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login'
driver.get(url)
```

I tried with Chrome and it worked for me!

Comment: It will just clearn the username/password prompt. This is not the actual login form. I can click cancel on the prompt and then get to the actual login form. Even in Firefox, you don't get that prompt. I used firefox in the code. In firefox, we get to the login page directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get around that popup you may try:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[.='Username']")))
```